# JNA: how to deal with unkown structs?

Tags: java, c, struct, jna

If I'm not mistaken, a [JNA Structure](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html) builds the struct by relying on the public fields of its corresponding Java class, which should extend `Structure`. My problem is that I need to pass a struct whose declaration is not known beforehand (let's say it's known at runtime). I just have a list of `Object`s, which the C library expects as a (reference to a) struct. Can I still use the `Structure` class or must I build a Memory object by hand, dealing with sizes, alignments/packing myself?

For example:

```
 /* native code */
 typedef struct mystruct {
     int x;
     float y;
 }  mystruct;

 void dosomething(mystruct * s) {
     s->y += s->x;
 }
```

And in Java:

```
 ...
 callFunctionWithSt("dosomething",
     new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(2),Float.valueOf(3.0)});
 ...

 void callFunctionWithSt(String funcName, Object[] structVals) {
     NativeLibrary nl = ...
     Pointer arg = ...  // or Memory ... or Structure
     // build structure
     for (Object objJava  : structVals) {
         valJna = convertFromJavaToJnaObject(objJava);
         // fill structure
     }
     f.invoke(arg);
 }

 Object convertFromJavaToJnaObject(Object) {
     // assume we know how to do this
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide native API examples?  If your native code uses opaque `struct`, it can do so only if all operations are performed on `struct*`, in which case you can use `Pointer` or `PointerType` and ignore the memory behind it.

Comment: I need to do exactly what it's usually done when passing a struct by reference. The native code is not opaque, is just that  I don't know at compile time the struct.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the content of the struct, then it is referred to as "opaque".

For opaque `struct *`, you can use `com.sun.jna.Pointer` to represent the structure address.

Comment: I know the content, it's only that I know it at runtime. To use a Pointer (should rather be Memory, I think), I would need to do myslef all the calculations of fields alignments that a Structure does.

Comment: If you only know the content and runtime, doesn't that imply that you have to calculate where stuff is on the fly?  Or are you talking about polymorphism?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use `Pointer` with an opaque `struct *`? In particular, how would you create the `Pointer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `Structure`. Define your interface method like this:

```
interface SomeLib {
    public static final SomeLib INSTANCE =
        (SomeLib) Native.loadLibrary("SomeLib", SomeLib.class);

    Pointer getSomeStruct();
}
```

Then when you call it, you just do this:

```
Pointer someValue = SomeLib.INSTANCE.getSomeStruct();
// do something here to determine what type it is
SpecificStructure struct = new SpecificStructure(someValue);
```

Comment: This assumes that the struct is being returned directly, but what if it is returned by reference? E.g. `int getSomeStruct(struct *s)`. That seems to be what the OP is talking about, since he mentions "passing a struct by reference".

Comment: Nope, the code I posted is for doing it by reference, which is why there is a pointer here. I'm not entirely sure how to handle it if it's returned directly, but I'm guessing making a ByValue subclass of the struct is the hint you'd need to do that.

Comment: Okay, well I'm not very familiar with the C lingo, but I meant "as a parameter." Maybe I misunderstood the OP. At any rate, I've asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036223/dealing-with-opaque-structs-in-jna?noredirect=1&lq=1) on this subject; if you know how to do it as a parameter, please share there.

Comment: Ah, as a parameter you can put `Pointer` in the parameter. Since it's an opaque struct, you must have got it from somewhere else, probably another function, which would have returned it as a pointer as well, so you just keep it and pass it as-is into another. In our actual production code, though, what we do is subclass PointerType with a name better matching what the library's headers called it, and then put that on all the methods. That way, it's harder to mess up and pass in the wrong thing.

Comment: No, I mean that the function I'm trying to call returns via a parameter and I need to somehow create the pointer without knowing anything about the struct. In C you would do something like `malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct))` (again, not a C programmer), but I'm not sure how to do this in Java. See the question I linked.

Comment: Usually what I've seen for that kind of API, I have had to pass a pointer to a pointer, and they allocate the structure and put a pointer to it in the location referred to by my pointer. If you're expected to pass a pointer to pass a struct back by value (?), I have no idea how that would work. I wouldn't even expect sizeof to work for opaque structs. If you do somehow know the size though, you can pass a Memory.

Comment: Well, in the usage example for the API, they create it as `SomeStruct x = NULL` and pass it as `&x`. But I can't do that in Java since I can't map `SomeStruct`, as it is opaque.

Comment: Which API is this? I don't get how that could work without somehow knowing the size... (There are questions about how to do it in C on Stack Overflow too.) If there is a way to get the size you'd just pass a Memory or something.

Comment: It's Apple's `Security.h`. I've added more information to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036223/dealing-with-opaque-structs-in-jna?noredirect=1&lq=1