# Getting an opaque struct returned by parameter in JNA

Tags: java, c, pointers, struct, jna

I'm trying to call a method in Apple's `Security.h` framework that returns a struct by reference, like so:

```
int findSomething(SomeStruct *s)
```

(Specifically, it's [this method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1397301-seckeychainfindgenericpassword?language=objc), and I'm trying to get `itemRef`. There's a usage example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH205-TP9).) The problem is that I don't know what fields `SomeStruct` has or how big it is. It only exists to be passed to other native library functions. So, I want something like this (Java):

```
interface SomeLib extends Library {
    int findSomething(Pointer p);
}

...
Pointer p = ... // Not sure how to make this
nativeLib.findSomething(p)
// Do something with p
```

If I could do `sizeof(SomeStruct)` in Java, I could create the pointer using JNAs `Memory`, I think. I could write a native method to return `sizeof(SomeStruct)`, but I don't want to add a native component to my own code.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981282/jna-how-to-deal-with-unkown-structs), but it asks about a case where the fields of `SomeStruct` are known at runtime, whereas, in my case, the fields are obscured intentionally by the library authors.

Comment: You only need `Memory` if you need to allocate space. If you just need the native peer value, why doesn't `Pointer` work just as you've described?

Comment: @DanielWiddis How do I create the pointer?

Comment: Thanks for the additional details.  You need a `PointerType` or one of its extensions.  @cubrr gave an excellent answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SecKeychainItemRef` type [is defined to be a **pointer to** the struct](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-55017/lib/SecBase.h.auto.html). This means that the `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword` function actually expects a *pointer to a pointer* as the `itemRef` argument, and as such, you can use the JNA `PointerByReference` class as the argument.

After a successful call, you can use [`PointerByReference.getValue()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference.html) to get the opaque pointer.

```
/* int SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
 *     Pointer keychainOrArray,
 *     int serviceNameLength,
 *     String serviceName,
 *     int accountNameLength,
 *     String accountName,
 *     IntByReference *passwordLength,
 *     PointerByReference passwordData,
 *     PointerByReference itemRef
 * );
 */

static void main() {
    IntByReference passLength = new IntByReference(0);
    PointerByReference passwordData = new PointerByReference();
    PointerByReference itemRef = new PointerByReference();

    int result = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
        keychainOrArray,
        "service name".length(),
        "service name",
        "account".length(),
        "account",
        passLength,
        passwordData,
        itemRef
    );

    if (result == 0) {
        System.out.printf(
            "OSStatus: %d, passDataPtr: 0x%08X, itemRefPtr: 0x%08X%n",
            result,
            Pointer.nativeValue(passwordData.getValue()),
            Pointer.nativeValue(itemRef.getValue())
        );
    } else {
        /* Use SecCopyErrorMessageString to get a human-readable message */
        System.out.printf("An error occurred: %d%n", result);
    }
}
```

If you're calling this method in an actual project, I would suggest creating a class named `SecKeychainItemRef` which extends the `PointerByReference` class. This communicates the argument's type to the reader in a clearer fashion, even if it doesn't let you access the internals of the struct.

Comment: What advantage is there to extending `PointerByReference` rather than simply `PointerType`?

Comment: @DanielWiddis `PointerByReference`'s `getValue` and `setValue` methods [deal with the additional level on indirection automatically](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/3a5787b9616862364ce92f9bb92c5661d743ac0a/src/com/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference.java#L44). It is a **pointer to a pointer**. A `PointerType` is simply a type of *pointer*. That is, it only wraps one level of indirection, whereas `PointerByReference` wraps two. Since the `itemRef` is a pointer to a pointer in this case, I would argue that it is semantically more correct to use `PointerByReference`.

Comment: Also worth noting that `PointerByReference` extends `ByReference`, meaning that it [automatically allocates memory for the pointer](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/3a5787b9616862364ce92f9bb92c5661d743ac0a/src/com/sun/jna/ptr/ByReference.java#L42).

Comment: Yes, this works. The only oddity is that subclasses of `PointerByReference` apparently need to be public. Does that mean the answer I accepted on this question is wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949920/macos-documentation-for-structs-in-security-h ?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I'm not sure what you mean by asking if it's wrong. How does a Java class having to be `public` tie into this?

Comment: Err, sorry, I meant does your answer mean that the answer I accepted to the question I linked in my previous comment is wrong?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon No, the answer seems correct to my eyes. I meant to ask that what makes you question the answer's validity?